# URLConnection does not handle content length via proxy correctly

Tags: java, proxy, urlconnection, http-proxy

I faced the following problem: When `URLConnection` is used via proxy the content length is always set to `-1`.

First I checked that proxy really returns the `Content-Length` (`lynx` and `wget` are also working via proxy; there is no other way to go to internet from local network):

```
$ lynx -source -head ftp://ftp.wipo.int/pub/published_pct_sequences/publication/2003/1218/WO03_104476/WO2003-104476-001.zip
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Jul 2007 17:02:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
Content-Length: 30745
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 02 Feb 2012 17:18:52 GMT

$ wget -S -X HEAD ftp://ftp.wipo.int/pub/published_pct_sequences/publication/2003/1218/WO03_104476/WO2003-104476-001.zip
--2012-04-03 19:36:54--  ftp://ftp.wipo.int/pub/published_pct_sequences/publication/2003/1218/WO03_104476/WO2003-104476-001.zip
Resolving proxy... 10.10.0.12
Connecting to proxy|10.10.0.12|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Jul 2007 17:02:37 GMT
  Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
  Content-Length: 30745
  Connection: close
  Age: 0
  Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2012 17:36:54 GMT
Length: 30745 (30K) [application/x-zip-compressed]
Saving to: `WO2003-104476-001.zip'
```

In Java I wrote:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://ftp.wipo.int/pub/published_pct_sequences/publication/2003/1218/WO03_104476/WO2003-104476-001.zip");
int length = url.openConnection().getContentLength();
logger.debug("Got length: " + length);
```

and I get `-1`. I started to debug `FtpURLConnection` and it turned out that the necessary information is in underlying `HttpURLConnection.responses` field however it is never properly populated from there:

[image]
(there is `Content-Length: 30745` in headers). The content length is not updated when you start reading the stream or even after the stream was read. Code:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://ftp.wipo.int/pub/published_pct_sequences/publication/2003/1218/WO03_104476/WO2003-104476-001.zip");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

logger.debug("Got length (1): " + connection.getContentLength());

InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int count = 0, len;
while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    count += len;
}

logger.debug("Got length (2): " + connection.getContentLength() + " but wanted " + count);
```

Output:

```
Got length (1): -1
Got length (2): -1 but wanted 30745
```

It seems like it is a bug in JDK6, so I have opened new [bug#7168608](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7168608).

- If somebody can help me to write the code should return correct content length for direct FTP connection, FTP connection via proxy and local `file:/` URLs I would appreciate.
- If given problem cannot be worked-around with JDK6, suggest any other library that definitely works for all cases I've mentioned ([Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/)?).

Comment: why do you need the content length?  is the actual stream of data correct?  if so, you don't need the content length, and everything is working fine.

Comment: @jtahlborn: The actual URL is correct (it is public FTP so you can test as well). I need to learn the content length **without** reading the stream to the end and it is obviously possible to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that proxies will often change the representation of the underlying entity. In your case I suspect the proxy is probably altering the transfer encoding. Which in turn makes the Content-Length meaningless even if supplied.

You are falling afoul of the following two sections of the HTTP 1.1 spec:

> [4.4 Message Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4)
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...
> 3. If a Content-Length header field (section 14.13) is present, its decimal value in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the transfer-length. The Content-Length header field MUST NOT be sent if these two lengths are different (i.e., if a Transfer-Encoding header field is present). If a message is received with both a Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field, the latter MUST be ignored.
>
> [14.41 Transfer-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.41)
>
> The Transfer-Encoding general-header field indicates what (if any) type of transformation has been applied to the message body in order to safely transfer it between the sender and the recipient. This differs from the content-coding in that the transfer-coding is a property of the message, not of the entity.
>
> ```
> Transfer-Encoding       = "Transfer-Encoding" ":" 1#transfer-coding
> ```
>
> Transfer-codings are defined in section 3.6. An example is:
>
> ```
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> ```
>
> If multiple encodings have been applied to an entity, the transfer- codings MUST be listed in the order in which they were applied. Additional information about the encoding parameters MAY be provided by other entity-header fields not defined by this specification.
>
> Many older HTTP/1.0 applications do not understand the Transfer- Encoding header.

So The URLConnection is then ignoring the `Content-Length` header, as per the spec because it is meaningless in the presence of *chunked* transfers

In your debugger screenshot it's not clear whether the `Transfer-Encoding` header is present. Please let us know...

On further investigation - it seems that lynx does not show all the headers returned when you issue a `lynx -head`. It is not showing the `Transfer-Encoding` header critical to this discussion.

Here's the proof of the discrepancy with a publically visible website

```
Ξ▶ lynx -useragent='dummy' -source -head http://www.bbc.co.uk                                                                                                                  
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache
X-Cache-Action: PASS (non-cacheable)
X-Cache-Age: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2012 13:33:06 GMT
Location: http://www.bbc.co.uk/mobile/
Connection: close

Ξ▶ wget -useragent='dummy' -S -X HEAD http://www.bbc.co.uk                                                                                                                 
--2012-04-03 14:33:22--  http://www.bbc.co.uk/
Resolving www.bbc.co.uk... 212.58.244.70
Connecting to www.bbc.co.uk|212.58.244.70|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: private, max-age=15
Etag: "7e0f292b2e5e4c33cac1bc033779813b"
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2012 13:33:22 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache-Action: MISS
X-Cache-Age: 0
X-LB-NoCache: true
Vary: Cookie
```

Since I am obviously not inside your network I can't replicate your exact circumstances, but please validate that you *really* aren't getting a Transfer-Encoding header when passing through a proxy.

Comment: Why it is meaningless in the presence of chunked transfers? If the server can communicate the length of whole stream, why consumer cannot use this information? This is a task of `URLConnection` to collect all chunks and hide this protocol detail from consumer. But OK, if spec says so... In my question from the output of `lynx` you can see that `Transfer-Encoding` is not present, so I cannot vote for your answer.

Comment: the lynx command in your question looks odd. Firstly `-head` is not appropriate for http URLs - the command as shown doesn't work for me with lynx 2.8.7rel.2. Secondly you'd expect that if the response had been through a proxy that you'd see a Via: header in the response. (although proxies don't always honour that)

Comment: Thanks for comment. The lynx command I've given works fine for me (tested for v2.8.6rel.5). HTTP HEAD is appropriate for any URLs, if you go **via proxy**: you can try any open proxy for that. If `Via` is not present, it does not mean the reply does not come from proxy. If you wish I can put `wget` command output, but it results the equivalent output. As I mentioned, I cannot go to internet another way: it is not possible due to firewall. Indeed our proxy is configured not to return `Via` to client. The output of `lynx` is exactly the same what is present in Java, please take it as fact.

Comment: I have edited my question. I believe that office Squid also follows the specification and will not return `Content-Length` if `Transfer-Encoding` is `chunked`. Also I don't believe that Squid can chunk FTP resource. It is **not** the problem of proxy, I hope I have convinced you. Your comments are very appreciated (I have learned about chunked transfer), but you dig into wrong direction. Also I don't think that Java "doublechecks" the spec and smartly ignores `Content-Length` if `Transfer-Encoding` is defined.

Comment: @dma_k - ok I don't have any further suggestions. Please update if you find the solution - will be interested to find out. good luck

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a "bug" in the jdk related to handling ftp connections which are proxied.  The FtpURLConnection delegates to an HttpURLConnection when a proxy is in use.  *however*, the FtpURLConnection doesn't seem to delegate any of the header management to this HttpURLConnection in this situation.  thus, you can correctly get the streams, but i don't think you can access any "header" values like content length or content type.  (this is based on a quick glance over the openjdk source for 1.6, i could have missed something).

Comment: @dma_k wrt bug in jdk - Apparently the FTP Client code has been totally overhauled for JDK 7. http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6893702 and http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6519647 seem related (although not exactly your problem). Have you tried JDK 7 ?

Comment: 2all: If you confirm the problem and can report it to Sun + share the lisnk, I would award the bounty (8 hours to go). Even if the problem is fixed in JDK7 (I haven't checked), I can't benefit from it: production AS is in Java6 and will be so next few years. Even worse: the code should be 1.5 compliant.

Comment: @dma_k - why is it everyone else's job to confirm your problem?  i gave you what i believe is the correct answer.  should be pretty simple for you to confirm it.

Comment: The problem that `HttpURLConnection` does not propagate headers to upper level is clear to me, and I spend hours looking into decompiled Sun code to prove this statement. However I could have overlooked the evident thing. Thanks for looking into OpenJDK code, but honestly I would expect somebody with 10k reputation to put solutions / workarounds on table. Do you have anything for the bullet points I've mentioned in my question? I do not ask **why** the problem occurs, I ask **how** to overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check I would do is to actually read the response (writing off the top of my head so expect mistakes):

```
URLConnection connection= url.openConnection();
InputStream input= connection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer= new byte[4096];
while(input.read(buffer) > 0)
  ;
logger.debug("Got length: " + getContentLength());
```

If the size you are getting is good, then look for a way for make URLConnection read the header but not the data to avoid reading the whole response.

Comment: Bad luck: that does not work (see my updated answer). You can test yourself, if you use any public proxy.